# How do create an array of doubles from numbers stored in a text file?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a text file named `tdata2.txt` which has the stock price data of several companies, it looks like this:

```
Apple
10.1 20 11 21.3 31 12.7 22 32.4 42 13
Microsoft  
23 45.1 78.2 48 93.2 67 86 99.8 22 12
Toyota 
34 76 34.3 67 89.5 23 56 34.9 83 76.1
...
```

(and so on)

I want to load the numbers into an  arrays
where

```
Double [] Apple = {10.1, 20, 11, 21.3, 31, 12.7, 22, 32.4, 42, 13}

Double [] Microsoft = {23, 45.1, 78.2, 48, 93.2, 67, 86, 99.8, 22, 12}

Double [] Toyota = {34, 76, 34.3, 67, 89.5, 23, 56, 34.9, 83, 76.1}
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Select A File");
    String FileName = keyboard.next();
    System.out.print(FileName);

    //Stores data from file into array
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName));
    try {
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
            System.out.print(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It can read in the file and print out the contents but thats about it.

There are not necessarily 10 numbers for each company, some have more some have less.

I am thinking of using an if statement, that as long as "FileName.hasNextDouble", then store it into the array. But I don't know how to skip the names of the companies or to store the names of the companies as the names of the arrays.

Comment: Does text file just consist of three lines of stock prices? or are the company names also included?

Comment: I edited the question based on the assumption that there is only one file that contains the company name and the stock quotes on adjacent lines. There can be more than three companies in the file. OP, please correct me if I misunderstood.

Comment: The company names are included in the text file.

line one contains the name of the company, 

line two is all it's stock prices, 

line three is the name of the second company, 
line four contains all the prices of the second company, and so on

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions made:

- The file will always start with a company name
- The line after a company name will always be a list of data for that company (separated by spaces)
- The line after a list of data will always be null, or a company name
  Provided the above assumptions are true, my answer should hold true as well.

---

Okay, so this is mainly a string parsing problem, and it's actually fairly simple (**assuming files are always properly formatted**, if they're not, this could be much more difficult). The general idea will be to read a line, store the company name, and then parse the data from the next line and put it in a Map. See code below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "..."; //Obtain this however you want

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) { //Open a try-with-resource loop. Try-with-resource will close the resource declared in the initial parenthesis automatically.
        Map<String, double[]> data = new HashMap<>(); //Create the mapping of company name -> data
        String line; //Initialize the line variable
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { //Read a line, while the next line is not null
            String name = line; //Remember the company name
            line = reader.readLine(); //Read the next line, with the data on it
            String[] doubles = line.split(" "); //Split the data into individual elements
            double[] parsedDoubles = new double[doubles.length]; //Create the actual data array, in which the parsed doubles will be stored
            for (int i = 0; i < doubles.length; i++) { //For each data element
                parsedDoubles[i] = Double.parseDouble(doubles[i]); //Parse the double and add it to the array
            }
            data.put(name, parsedDoubles); //Record the array in the map
        }
        double[] toyota = data.get("Toyota"); //Data can now be accessed by calling the get method on map
    } catch (IOException e) { //Catch those pesky IO exceptions
        e.printStackTrace(); //Print those pesky IO exceptions
    }

}
```

---

If anything about my answer is unclear, or you don't understand (or are unfamiliar with) a technique I'm using, please post a comment and I'll edit my answer.

---

**Important Note:** This is not a "robust" or "general purpose" solution. If this is for a class or 1 time parse, the above code should be fine, but if you're writing a long term application or library, think about ways to generalize the problem to handle potential unexpected cases (such as files with multiple lines of data, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I'll just throw in all. There are many variations, and I am unsure whether java 8 Stream is not too state-of-the-art.

```
Map<String, List<Double>> mapBrandToCourses = new TreeMap<>();

Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

for (int i = 0; i + 1 < lines.size(); i += 2) {
    String brand = lines.get(i);

    String coursesLine = lines.get(i + 1);
    String[] courseValues = coursesLine.split("\\s+");

    List<Double> courses = Stream.of(courseValues)
        .map(Double::parseDouble)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    mapBrandToCourses.put(brand, courses);
}
```

This creates a map of brand name to list of course values. Looking for the **javadoc** (in the net) will help tremendously.

A note: `Double` is the object wrapper for the `double` primitive type. Except of containers like List use the primitive type whereever possible.

Comment: +1 java 8 is awesome, I wish more classes taught it and more libraries used it. (Also, quick question, why TreeMap?)

Comment: @Meguy To have listing the map sorted by brand name: Apple - Microsoft - Toyota indeed. Yes, java 8 gives us code pieces resembling poetry in a forest of prose.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make make the arrays have a custom string as their name. You can, however, use a HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> companies = new HashMap<>();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName));
try {
    boolean isCompanyLine = True;
    String companyName = '';
    for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {

        if (isCompanyLine) {
            companyName = line;
        } else {
            ArrayList<Double> stockPrices = new ArrayList<>();

            for (String price : line.split(' ')) {
                stockPrices.add(Double.parseDouble(price));
            }

            companies.put(companyName, stockPrices);
        }
        isCompanyLine = ! isCompanyLine;
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This assumes that every other line is a company, that there are no empty lines, and that the stock price lines are strictly space-separated. This code can be modified if any of these assumptions are invalid.

Also, you might not want to use doubles to store money values. If this is a money-critical application, use integers, or something like BigDecimal that has arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
double[] Apple = {}, Microsoft = {}, Toyota = {};

Path path = Paths.get("stock.txt");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);

for (int i = 0, size = lines.size(); i < size; i += 2) {
    double[] stocks = Stream.of(lines.get(i + 1).split("\\s+"))
        .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
        .toArray();
    switch (lines.get(i).trim()) {
    case "Apple" : Apple = stocks; break;
    case "Microsoft" : Microsoft = stocks; break;
    case "Toyota" : Toyota = stocks; break;
    }
}
```